FSimage and Editlogs Merging in HDFS
HDFS cluster in HA enabled with one active namenode and one standby namenode. During checkpointing in how editlogs and fsimage get merged ?
I tired with the source code check but got confused by the flow, Can someone help on this?, how editlogs and fsimage file get merged ?
